# bad value, control character in path component

Tags: html

i get this problem when i try to validate my code:

Line 15, Column 21: Bad value http://html5resetcss.googlecode.com/files/html5reset-1.6.1css”>↩ ↩ ↩↩↩
Syntax of IRI reference:
Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

Line 15, Column 20: Attribute container not allowed on element link at this point.

Attributes for element link:
Global attributes
href
crossorigin
rel
media
hreflang
type
sizes
Also, the title attribute has special semantics on this element.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Makers</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Survival in Russia">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Russia, Survival">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="opmaak.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://html5resetcss.googlecode.com/files/html5reset-1.6.1.css”>

    </head>

<body>
<div id=" container>
<header>
       <h1>Survival in Russia</h1>     



</header>
<div class="content">

            <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="intro.html">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Intro</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Our goal</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="task.html">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Task</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">What you're going to do</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                            <a href="process.html">Process</a>
                            <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>

                         </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="evaluation.html">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Evaluation</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">How did you do?</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="conclusion.html">
                        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Conclusion</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">What have you learned?</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="teacherpage.html">
                        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Teacherpage</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">For teachers</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="makers.html">
                        <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="foto Rusland"/>
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">Makers</span>
                            <span class="sdt_descr">Joran and Zjenja</span>
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
        <p>This webquest is made by Joran Rust and Zjenja Jegorov, both students of the Anna van Rijn.</p>
        <p>Thanks for using our site! We hope that you've learned a lot of new things.</p>
        </div>

 <span class="reference">
                <a href="index.html">back to the first page</a>
            </span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
    $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.find('img')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({
                'width':'170px',
                'height':'170px',
                'left':'0px'
             },400,'easeOutBack')
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_wrap')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_active')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
            var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
            if($sub_menu.length){
                var left = '170px';
                if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                    left = '-170px';
                $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
            }   
        });
    }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
        if($sub_menu.length)
            $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

        $elem.find('.sdt_active')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
             .andSelf().find('img')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({
                'width':'0px',
                'height':'0px',
                'left':'85px'},400)
             .andSelf()
             .find('.sdt_wrap')
             .stop(true)
             .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
    });
});
        </script>







</body>
</html>
```

how to fix this?

Comment: First of all, there is a period missing before css

Answer (score 0):

you have a "." missing before css and you shouldn't use dots in your file name it is bad practice

:)

Comment: hmm thnx, but sorry for a stupid question, but where? :$ sorry this is the first time that im using html :)

Comment: in your css url <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://html5resetcss.googlecode.com/files/html5reset-1_6_1.css”>

Comment: ohh i see, and where should the "." be placed?

Comment: i have put it in there in your href before "css"

Comment: as far as i can see for your first problem you css file might not exist have you double checked the directory

Comment: is there any code you have not added as your error says line 15 and you css link isnt on line 15?

Answer (score 0):

In the second `link` element (line break added here for convenience),

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=
"http://html5resetcss.googlecode.com/files/html5reset-1.6.1.css”>
```

the `href` attribute value is not properly terminated. When preceded by an Ascii quotation mark " (U+2022), it must be terminated by that same character. But before the > character, the code has RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK U+201D ”, which is just yet another data character. So an HTML parser keeps scanning for an Ascii quotation mark, and thus the `href` value is all wrong etc.

The fix is to replace ” by " or to remove both the leading " and the ” (by HTML5 rules, the attribute value does not need to be quoted).

Comment: Bad value container>↩<header>↩ <h1>Survival in Russia</h1> ↩ ↩↩↩</header>↩<div class= for attribute id on element div: An ID must not contain whitespace.
<div class="content">
Syntax of id:
An ID consists of at least one character but must not contain any whitespace

Comment: Yes, you get other errors, because now the validator processes the markup further. Just fix the errors, one at a time if needed. Sometimes the error can be hard to spot, but the length of the message is a clue here: earlier, there is the construct `<div id=" container>` the closing quote is missing, causing a similar problem. The fix is to add the closing quote (or to remove the opening quote).